# coreml prediction Failure Reason: Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, coreml, imessagefilter

I trained a text classification model using the Coreml tool and put it into the swiftui project by document. In the main application it worked fine, but in the SMS filtering extension it was abnormal. Hint:
Failure Reason: Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Without a specific description, I used breakpoints to find a problem in the following line:

try?  model.prediction(text:message)

The model class I used was automatically generated by xcode.

The same usage was fine on the main app, the sms extension, which crashed when I tried to send SMS to the test device.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.